Boy possesed by a spirit
I'm looking for a manga where the main character attends a magic high school, a typical fantasy setting. However, the twist is that he is possessed by some kind of evil god/spirit/ghost. In one lesson, he needs to train his sword spirit, and that's where the evil spirit tries to take over his body. He also has a female friend who is possessed or almost possessed by an evil fire sword called Ifrit. He helps her defeat it and harnesses it as her power. As far as I know, it's not an isekai. Please help me find it!

I found it, it was Ichiokunen Button o Rendashita Ore wa, Kidzuitara Saikyou ni Natteita ~Rakudai Kenshi no Gakuin Musou~ (one long name; English: "I Kept Pressing the 100-Million-Year Button and Came Out on Top: The Unbeatable Reject Swordsman").
Summary from Wikipedia:

Even though he practices all day, Allen Rodol is on the verge of flunking out of Grand Swordcraft Academy due to his total lack of talent. To make matters worse, class prodigy Doriel, challenges him to a duel where it's win or face expulsion. However, the night before his duel, a mysterious hermit grants him a button that will give him one hundred million years to train in an alternate reality when pressed. Allen with all his doubts presses that button, after experiencing its effect he kept pushing the button many times. Now with over a billion years of straight practice under his belt, the world is about to see what the “Reject Swordsman” can really do!


I feel like the author might not know how long a billion years is! I think someone would probably get as good as they physically could at sword fighting within the first millenium, and then spend the remaining 999,999,000 years being horribly bored....
